# isolating grouped digits from integer input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, integer

My aim is to be able to input a large (6 digit) number into a terminal and for it to return the middle two digits, swapped.

My code is as follows:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
e = int(input())
f = int(input())

addition = ((a * 0) + (b * 0) + (d * 10))
addition_two = ((c) + (e * 0) + (f * 0))
print(addition + addition_2)
```

I'm unsure of how to adjust this in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: Do you understand how the decimal number system works? Why do you multiply the input values with 0?

Comment: Did the given solution not work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all the complexity. If you only want the middle two digits (and they're swapped), you can simply use:

```
n = input("Enter number: ")
ans = n[2:4]
return int(ans) //if you want int type, else ans would suffice as str
```

Comment: If it solves your purpose, consider upvoting/marking it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Ask for inputs until it is 6 long and only consists of digits. there is no need to convert anything to a number, you can work with the string directly by slicing it correctly:

```
while True:
    k = input("6 digit number")
    if not all(c.isdigit() for c in k) or len(k) != 6:
        print("Not a six digit number")
    else:
        break

# string slicing:
#   first 2 letters
#   reversed 4th and 3rd letter
#   remaining letters
print(k[:2] + k[3:1:-1] + k[4:])
```

See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) and [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)